# Проверить Bundle на null

Tags: java, android, android-bundle

При переходе в следующий фрагмент, нужно проверить, передал ли `Bundle` строку или нет, если строка не пустая, добавиться элемент в `RecyclerView`, проще говоря, мне нужно проверить на null, но я не пойму как это сделать с `Bundle`.

Пишу следующее

```
        if (bundle.containsKey("SearchImage1") == null){
            itemGallery.add(new ItemGallery(bundle.getString("SearchImage1")));
        }
```

Но это является не правильной записью, помогите правильно написать.

Comment: Помимо ответа вы еще и условия не правильные пишите. У вас условие - если `== null`, а судя по вопросу нужно было писать `!=null`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

метод `containsKey()`

- возвращает `true`, если переданный ключ есть в Bundle
- возвращает `false`, если данного ключа в Bundle нет

соответственно проверка на `null` здесь лишняя.

Доcтаточно просто:

```java
if (bundle.containsKey("SearchImage1")){
    itemGallery.add(new ItemGallery(bundle.getString("SearchImage1")));
}
```

В Вашем же случае будет происходить следующее.
Допустим что в `bundle` есть ключ `SearchImage1`.
В этом случае `bundle.containsKey("SearchImage1")` вернет `true`
Соответственно проверка сведется к следующей:

```java
if (true == null){
   //...
}
```

И данная проверка никак не может быть истинной, соответственно вы не войдёте внутрь условия.
Не думаю, что это то что вы планировали.